# Store a tree in a database

Tags: database, algorithm, hierarchical-data

I'm currently trying to figure out the best way to store a tree in a database (mysql probably if it is possible).
These are the constraints and the use of the tree :

- Each nodes can have 4 children max but it is better if it is scalable and up to x children
- Each child have a weight (if a parent has 3 leaf, the probability to use each of them could be 40%, 40% and 20% for example).
- Around 40K nodes would be stored in the database, but it is better if it is scalable and ok with 1M for example
- No data will be written in the database, just reading
- The goal is to have very good reading performance from the root to a specific leaf, not to be able to display all the tree at once

For the moment I have thought to use the adjacency list model : https://www.simple-talk.com/content/article.aspx?article=1234 with weight stored as a field.

Is this ok for you, or is there a better way to store this in a database ?

Comment: As far as I know, SQL databases have poor performance with linked or recursive data like trees.

Comment: @SergeRogatch: then you have used the wrong databases (or wrong queries). Recursive queries are quite efficient.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You should maybe consider using a graph database such as neo4j.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are talking about a tree, and not a generic graph - what about a file system? You should be able to get good performance. You might even store it in memory. It could easily scale to 1M nodes, as well. And you get tools for backups, browsing the tree etc for free.

Sometimes the simplest solution is the best.

Comment: And store the data for each node in file ? Sure it will be ok to have to open a file every time to get the properties ?

Comment: Not sure, but it's probably one hours work to find out. Check out [tmpfs](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/what-is-devshm-and-its-practical-usage.html). Also depends on how much of the directory structure you can use for your tree traversal, I guess. :)